# Jquery SlickGrid - add distinction to grouped rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, slickgrid

So this is a very specific question for SlickGrid, but I was wondering if anyone has ever tried to change the way the rows look when grouped?  I was thinking that it would be cool to add a border around the grouped rows to show that they are part of that heading.

The way that SlickGrid works doesn't give any indication the rows are grouped in the DOM, they just appear under the header.  I have tried to do something like this:

```
dataView.getItemMetadata = function(index) {
     return {cssClasses: "myRowCssClass"};                        
}
```

but unfortunately, this broke other things in terms of the grouping.  There is some stuff in the native `getItemMetadata` function that the groupBy function needs to process.  I could copy that stuff into this function and add a condition for this, but that doesn't seem right.  Does anyone who has some experience with SlickGrid know how to achieve this effect?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question. But I have done something similar to what you are asking about.

In my data, I have information about assets at several sites within an organization. So for each group of records, the name of the site will be the same. As I am reading my data (obtained via an $.ajax call), whenever the site name changes, I insert a 'parent' row in the data array.

I wanted to display these parent rows in bold. I accomplished this by defining a CSS class for the parent rows and using getItemMetadata() to apply the class.

```
dataView.getItemMetadata = function(row) {
    if (row is a parent) {
        return { 'cssClasses' : 'my-parent-row-class' };
    }
};
```

In my application, I also made use of Slickgrid filters and a 'toggle' class (applied in a click handler) to implement a drill-down feature where you can click on a parent row and collapse/expand the rows grouped under that parent row.

I hope this helps.

Tim